# I did this api in node.js with an database on elephantSQL, but I have no idea how can I deploy this

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, deployment

I'm relatively beginner at this, but I have searched on youtube different ways to deploy this but in the most of the videos people uses millions of frameworks like prisma, typescript and I just wanted to deploy this simple api in node.js with a database in postgree, can anyone help me?

github link: [text](https://github.com/JoaoVitorProjetos/login-node)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it